# ¿Herramientas de creación de Dashboards open source?

Tags: web

Estoy buscando herramientas de creación de dashboard, algo que me permita extraer datos de X base de datos y ponerla en X sitio, para después poder subirlo a un servidor web, ¿Qué puedo utilizar?

La idea es hacer una dashboard con información extraida de diferentes sitios para facilitar el trabajo a gente de administración.

Me interesaría conseguir varias herramientas para después obtener pros y contras de cada una.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Hola Aritz. Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones porque pides sugerencias/recomendaciones de qué herramientas usar. Has de investigar y elegir una. Si durante el desarrollo tienes problemas concretos , pregunta aqui siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: No sabía donde podía preguntar esto, tras investigar y ver varias herramientas no había encontrado ninguna, es por eso que he decidido acudir, siento si no era una pregunta apropiada, no volverá a ocurrir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aún no he tenido ocasión de utilizarlas pero dos de las que mejores referencias son:

- [Mozaik](http://mozaik.rocks/)
- [Grafana](https://grafana.com/)

Comment: ¿Son gratis y open source?

Comment: Sí. Si no me equivoco ambos se distribuyen bajo licencia MIT (aquí está la de Mozaik: https://github.com/plouc/mozaik/blob/master/LICENSE.md) lo cual implica que es gratis incluso para uso comercial

Comment: Vale, buscaré el de grafana, que vista la información, al menos para este proyecto creo que es el que más nos interesa, muchas gracias.